# Android Search function using a string from an EditText

Tags: android

The Search function in my Android app works. I'm using `onSearchRequested()`; to invoke the Search function. Now what I'd like to do is not use `onSearchRequested()`; and pass a string from an `EditText` to the search method and display the results in a List. Here's my search as it's working when `onSearchRequested` is called:

`SearchPage` Activity:

```
    DBHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
    DBHelper.open();
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);

    }
    //--- END onSearchRequested


private void showResults(String query) {
    Cursor cursor = DBHelper.searchDB(query);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] searchFrom = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_YEAR,
            DBAdapter.KEY_MAKE, DBAdapter.KEY_MODEL };
    int[] displayHere = new int[] { R.id.rYearTV, R.id.rMakeTV,
            R.id.rModelTV };

    final SimpleCursorAdapter records = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.record_2, cursor, searchFrom, displayHere);

    setListAdapter(records);
```

`DBAdapter` Activity:

```
//--- GET RECORDS FOR SEARCH
    public Cursor searchDB(String query) { 

    String[] parts = query.split(" "); 

    String queryString = ""; 
    for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) { 
        queryString += KEY_YEAR + " LIKE '%" + parts[i] + "%' OR "; 
        queryString += KEY_MAKE + " LIKE '%" + parts[i] + "%' OR "; 
        queryString += KEY_MODEL + " LIKE '%" + parts[i] + "%'"; 
        if(i != (parts.length - 1)) { 
            queryString += " OR "; 
        } 
    } 

    return db.query(true, DB_TABLE,  
        new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_SDATE, KEY_YEAR, KEY_MAKE, KEY_MODEL },  
        queryString, null, null, null, null, null); 
}
//--- END Get Records for Search
```

I'd like to pass a String into the search function `String searchData = searchEditText.getText().toString();` and have the search function go to work on the passed string by pressing a "Search" button. Can someone help get me started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `EditText` like that in your layout:

```
       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_query"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="search"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text" />
```

And in your Activity's `onCreate`:

```
EditText searchQuery = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_query);
searchQuery.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    String searchData = searchQuery.getText().toString();
                            showResults(searchData); //passing string to search in your database to your method
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
    });
```

`setOnEditorActionListener` is used to perform search when user presses <kbd>search</kbd> button on keayboard. You can read more about `imeActions` [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html).

According to your code call `showResults(searchData);` to make search and display results in a list.

---

**EDIT:**
According to your code call it in `SearchPage` Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setContentView and other your features

    DBHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
    DBHelper.open();

    EditText searchQuery = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_query);

    Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String searchData = searchQuery.getText().toString();
            showResults(searchQuery);
        }
    });
}

private void showResults(String query) {
    Cursor cursor = DBHelper.searchDB(query);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] searchFrom = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_YEAR,
            DBAdapter.KEY_MAKE, DBAdapter.KEY_MODEL };
    int[] displayHere = new int[] { R.id.rYearTV, R.id.rMakeTV,
            R.id.rModelTV };

    final SimpleCursorAdapter records = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.record_2, cursor, searchFrom, displayHere);

    setListAdapter(records);
}
```

Comment: I have a button to press to perform the search, does the above code go into the button's code? and you have //do your search in the above code, would I do the search by writing: `DBHelper = new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());
 DBHelper.open();    
 DBHelper.searchDB(searchData);
 DBHelper.close();`

Comment: sorry if I'm asking too many questions, I'm a rookie at Android

Comment: All were once rookies. The above code is used to perform search when user presses the `search icon` on keyboard (often in the lower right corner of the keyboard). So you can use it for users convenience. Edited my answer.